# HTML Table - Nested Table Row using Knockout

Tags: json, html, knockout.js

I have a JSON object where EntityCode, EntityName, TagName, and TaskName (from TagList) are to be table column headers.

StatusFlagName in TaskRecordList is then to be in a nested row under it's related TaskName. The StatusFlagName values should be directly below the TaskName.

How do I get this working? The StatusFlagName will not display.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
this.taskRecords = ko.observableArray([
{
 EntityCode: "name",
  EntityName: "name desc23",
  TagName: "L1",
  TaskList: [
   {
     TaskName: "TaskABC",
      TaskRecordList: [
       { 
         StatusFlagName: "OK"
        },
        { 
         StatusFlagName: "TEST"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
     TaskName: "TaskDEF",
      TaskRecordList: [
       { 
         StatusFlagName: "Error"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]);
  
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody data-bind="foreach: taskRecords">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: EntityCode"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: EntityName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: TagName"></td>
                <td></td>
                <!--ko foreach: TaskList-->
                <td data-bind="text: TaskName">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <!--ko foreach: TaskRecordList-->
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="text: StatusFlagName"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <!--/ko-->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <!--/ko-->
                
            </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use  `<td data-bind="text: TaskName">` knockout will replace whatever you have inside this tag with the value of `TaskName` as a text that's why your last nested table is being replaced with `TaskName` value.

You can add a `div` or `span` for `TaskName` something like below :

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: taskRecords">
      <tr>
         <td data-bind="text: EntityCode"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: EntityName"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: TagName"></td>
         <td></td>
         <!--ko foreach: TaskList-->
         <td> 
            <div data-bind="text: TaskName"></div>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <!--ko foreach: TaskRecordList-->
                  <tr>
                     <td data-bind="text: StatusFlagName"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <!--/ko-->
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
         <!--/ko-->

      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do it!